# Cassandra - smaller partitions caused performance issues

Tags: cassandra, nosql, bigdata, cassandra-3.0

I have a schema in Cassandra where I store information about trades. The current schema has **unbound partitions**, which is probably the main antipattern, so right now I am working on a new schema with **buckets** that limit single partition size to trades for one hour, so the bucket looks like that: `2021-06-21-12` (trades that occurred on 2021-06-21 from 12:00 to 13:00)
Apart from bucketing, I made a couple of additional changes to the new schema:

- set **TTL**
- changed configuration of **TimeWindowCompactionStrategy** -  window size has 10 days, for old schema it has 1 day. According to the documentation, we should aim at having 20-30 sstables, so because I am going to store trades for one year I was thinking that the new setting is better.
- changed **bloom_filter_fp_chance** from 0.1 to 0.01 - I noticed a lot of false-positive at the beginning when I have 0.1 - 43%, then when changed to 0.01, false-positive almost does not exist
- in the old schema we have **key cache** disabled, enabled **row cache** (100), which for me does not make sense, so in the new schema, there is key cache enabled and row cache disabled.

After migrating 8 days of data, I run a couple of queries to validate if data was properly migrated.

**Even that I have a better schema (at least I believe so), more resources in the new Cassandra (more RAM, SSD instead of standard disks) I got worse performance!**

I am performing the following query for old and new schema:

`select sum(size) from old_trades where .... and ts > '2021-06-12 12:00:00' and ts < '2021-06-12 13:00:00'`

`select sum(size) from new_trades where .... and bucket='2021-06-12-12';`

On cqlsh, where by default paging is set to 100, **request for old schema takes 5 seconds, for new schema 8 seconds.**

I am wondering how it is possible. In the production environment, queries like `select sum(size)` won't be executed, I use it as verification if data are correctly migrated, but still, it is a little bit frightening and counterintuitive that new shiny schema loses with the old schema.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we've found out the culprit: in the new Cassandra configuration, we had Xmn set to 5MB by mistake, in the old Cassandra we had Xmn set 512MB. After the fix, our queries to the new schema were two times faster than to the old schema.